# AMQP 1.0 Qpid JMS and an Issue with Failover/Reconnect

Tags: jms, amqp, failover, qpid, reconnect

Im using Qpid JMS 0.8.0 library in order to implement a standalone java AMQP client. Because the underlying transport connection tends to break every couple of hours I have set the reconnection using following configuration:

failover:(amqps://someurl:5671)?failover.reconnectDelay=2000&failover.warnAfterReconnectAttempts=1

In accordance with Qpid client configuration explanation page I expect my client to keep trying to reconnect increasing the attempt delays for factor 2 (starting with 2 seconds). Instead, according to the log file, only two attempts to reconnect have been performed when a connection failure was detected and at the end the whole client application has been terminated, what I definitively would like to avoid! Here is the log file:

2016-03-22 14:29:40 INFO  AmqpProvider:1190 - IdleTimeoutCheck closed the transport due to the peer exceeding our requested idle-timeout.
2016-03-22 14:29:40 DEBUG FailoverProvider:761 - Failover: the provider reports failure: Transport closed due to the peer exceeding our requested idle-timeout
2016-03-22 14:29:40 DEBUG FailoverProvider:519 - handling Provider failure: Transport closed due to the peer exceeding our requested idle-timeout
2016-03-22 14:29:40 DEBUG FailoverProvider:653 - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://publish.preops.nm.eurocontrol.int:5671 in-progress
2016-03-22 14:29:40 INFO  FailoverProvider:659 - Connection attempt:[1] to: amqps://publish.preops.nm.eurocontrol.int:5671 failed
2016-03-22 14:29:40 WARN  FailoverProvider:686 - Failed to connect after: 1 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
2016-03-22 14:29:42 DEBUG FailoverProvider:653 - Connection attempt:[2] to: amqps://publish.preops.nm.eurocontrol.int:5671 in-progress
2016-03-22 14:29:42 INFO  FailoverProvider:659 - Connection attempt:[2] to: amqps://publish.preops.nm.eurocontrol.int:5671 failed
2016-03-22 14:29:42 WARN  FailoverProvider:686 - Failed to connect after: 2 attempt(s) continuing to retry.
2016-03-22 14:29:43 DEBUG ThreadPoolUtils:156 - Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@778970af[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 0.000 seconds.
2016-03-22 14:29:45 DEBUG ThreadPoolUtils:192 - Waited 2.004 seconds for ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@877a470[Shutting down, pool size = 1, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 1, completed tasks = 3] to terminate...
2016-03-22 14:29:46 DEBUG ThreadPoolUtils:156 - Shutdown of ExecutorService: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor@877a470[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 4] is shutdown: true and terminated: true took: 2.889 seconds.

Any idea, what I’m doing wrong here? Basically, what I'm looking for to achieve is a client which is capable to detect transport connection failure and try to reconnect every 5-10 seconds.

Many thanks!

Comment: Seems like something best asked on the Qpid mailing lists with sample code to demonstrate your usage.

Comment: Thx Tim, I also thought so and have already send an email to the qpid mailing list...

Comment: Hi @AleksB did Qpid team ever replied you back? if so, can you please send the link or tell me what was the response. thnx